# showing cells with a particular symbols in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

i have not seen such question, so if you happen to know the answer or have seen the same question, please let me know

i have a dataframe in pandas with 4 columns and 5k rows, one of the columns is "price" and i need to do some manipulations with it. but the data was parsed from web-page and it is not clean, so i cannot convert this column to integer type after getting rid of dollar sign and comas. i found out that it also contains data in the format `3500/mo`. so i need to filter cells with `/mo` and decide whether i can drop them, basing on how many of those i have and what is the price.

now, i have managed to count those cells using

```
df["price"].str.contains("/").sum()
```

but when i want to see those cells, i cannot do that, because when i create another variable to extract slash-containing cells and use "contains" or smth, i get the series with true/false values - showing me the condition of whether the cell does or does not contain that slash, while i actually need to see cells themselves. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the boolean mask returned by `df["price"].str.contains("/")` as index to get the respective rows, i.e., `df[df["price"].str.contains("/")]` (cf. [the pandas docs on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)).